ER model of an online bookstore
By my study, I am required to create an ER model. This is the first time I have done this, and I am not sure if the connections are correct. Can you please tell me if they look correct?
Thank you in advance.
P.S. One of the requirements is the availability of all types of connections


Well, yes, orders from the same customer can be sent to different addresses, and I think it would be more convenient if they could be saved instead of having to be entered every time.
